# Run function only on a certain window width jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to run this function only when the size is lower than 768px and when resizing the screen but the function still runing when i resize to a bigger screen than 768

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).on("resize", function(e) {
    checkScreenSize();
  });

  checkScreenSize();

  function checkScreenSize() {
    var newWindowWidth = $(window).width();
    if (newWindowWidth < 768) {
      var el = $('#infobarContainer .uspTag'),
        i = 0;
      $(el[0]).show();

      (function loop() {
        el.delay(3000).fadeOut(500).eq(++i % el.length).fadeIn(600, loop);
      }());
    }


  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: [it doesn't work](https://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/) isn't a useful description of the problem.

Comment: Your live demo is trying to modify HTML elements you didn't include in it.

Comment: *still running* - you don't have an exit condition - every time you resize the window you start a new `loop()` with no way to exit it.   As a start, add the `$(window).width()` check as the first line of `loop()` so it only works on smaller screens. You'll still have the issue of it running multiple times

Comment: @freedomn-m but i have $(window).width() and i'm checking if the size is lower than 768 run the function , otherwise don't

Comment: ...and it continues to run when you resize, so you resize the window again and it's still less than 768 so you start the loop a second time ... then you resize the window again and it's still less than 768 so you start the loop *again*...etc.    Do you think the window can only be resized once?

Comment: @freedomn-m well, now i got it, thanks for taking time to explain it to me, what do u suggest to solve it then ? Do i need to have an ellse statment ?